# Setting Spring boot actuator with oAuth2 in the Authorisation server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-actuator

I have two spring boot server applications (Spring boot 1.5.2), the first one is the resource server and the second is the authorisation server (oAuth2), I have added Spring boot actuator to both servers and configured both with the following properties:

```
management.security.roles=ROLE_MYADMINROLE
management.context-path=/myactuator
```

In the resource server, I can access the actuator endpoints using a token obtained from the authorisation server for a user who hold the role `ROLE_MYADMINROLE`.

But in the authorisation server itself, I could not get the token working at the first place (Http Basic was working), to use the tokens, I have added a resource server configuration to it, and set the filter order at 3 after reading Spring boot documentation

```
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3
```

> OAuth2 resources are protected by a filter chain with order `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order` and the default is after the filter protecting the actuator endpoints by default (so actuator endpoints will stay on HTTP Basic unless you change the order).

In [Spring boot release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#oauth-2-resource-filter) we have this regarding this filter order:

> OAuth 2 Resource Filter
>
> The default order of the OAuth2 resource filter has changed from 3 to
>   SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER - 1. This places it after the
>   actuator endpoints but before the basic authentication filter chain.
>   The default can be restored by setting
>   `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order` = 3

Now my actuator endpoint in the authorisation server accepts tokens issued from the same server, the question is why the default is Http Basic for the actuator endpoints? I assume oAuth2 is more secure than Http Basic?  why I had to change the filter order in the authorisation server but not in the resource server? Here I am looking for an explanation for this rather than a solution as I have got this working as I want already.