# Spring Boot - OAuth2 - All requests are being forbidden

Tags: java, spring, oauth

I have a spring boot application which enables REST with OAuth (both Application & Resource server).

MyApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

OAuthConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        configurer.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
        .inMemory()
        .withClient("app")
        .secret("secret")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600)
        .scopes("read", "write")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
        .resourceIds("resources");
    }
}
```

SimpleCorsFilter.java

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {
    public SimpleCorsFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, content-type");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/signup");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private PanelService testService;

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public Panel getTest() throws Exception {
        return testService.get();
    }
}
```

I am successfully able to generate the token and also able to get a new token by calling the refresh_token using the above setup.
The problem is that, my rest calls are also returning data irrespective of ouath token being passed or not. `/test` always returns data with or without the token.

I also tried different options in HTTP security. The below one always throws Forbidden even though I use a valid token.

```
http.csrf().disable();
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.httpBasic();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question to help all those who are facing a similar problem.

Set the following property in application.properties file

```
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3
```

- [SpringBoot 1.5.x + Security + OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822875/springboot-1-5-x-security-oauth2)
- [Setting Spring boot actuator with oAuth2 in the Authorisation server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526821/setting-spring-boot-actuator-with-oauth2-in-the-authorisation-server)
- [Authentication is not working in spring boot 1.5.2 and Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664070/authentication-is-not-working-in-spring-boot-1-5-2-and-oauth2)

Also in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter add the following lines in configuring HttpSecurity (I am not sure how this piece of code made it work - I am still investigating)

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    ...
}
```

The above code is referenced in the below two examples (refer the GitHub code)

https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50

http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/

Comment: Just `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3` made it work.

Comment: @SRCM Can you please help me with my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65229165/springboot-1-5-x-issues-with-spring-security-resourceserverconfigureradapter